# callouts package is inserting spaces around figures

Tags: captions, annotations

I want to annotate subfigures I have designed in other software by including in the top left corner letter identifiers such as `(a)` etc. I am using the [`callouts`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/callouts) package in my main document as I am already loading TikZ so the extra overhead is negligible. However, the package seems to be inserting extra space around figures as can be seen here:

[image]

whereas a figure without using the `\begin{annotate}` environment from the `callouts` package gives:

[image]

What is the reason for this slight extra horizontal space and significant vertical space when using the `\begin{annotate}` environment and how can I get rid of it please?

The `.sty` file for `callouts` is only 93 lines but I cannot work out what is causing the interaction, I `\renewenvironment`'ed the environment definition to add `%` at the end of each line but it had no effect. The definition of the environment `\begin{annotate}` is (courtesy of the author Markus Stuetz):

```
\newenvironment{annotate}[2]%[num]%
{ \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#2]% }%
% Annotate
\node (pic) at (0,0) {#1};%
\newdimen\xtic
\newdimen\ytic
\pgfextractx\xtic{\pgfpointanchor{pic}{east}}
\pgfmathparse{int(\xtic/1cm)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xtic{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfextracty\ytic{\pgfpointanchor{pic}{north}}
\pgfmathparse{int(\ytic/1cm)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ytic{\pgfmathresult}
}%
{ \end{tikzpicture} }
```

Putting content within the `annotate` environment had no effect, using this:

```
\begin{annotate}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}{1}
\node[draw] at (0, 0) {\textbf{(a)}};
\end{annotate}
```

caused the same space.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{callouts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom,labelfont={bf, small}, labelsep=period, textfont={small}, aboveskip=6pt, belowskip=-6pt, singlelinecheck=off, justification=justified}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{annotate}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}{1}
\node[draw] at (0, 0) {\textbf{(a)}};
\end{annotate}
\caption{With annotate}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Without annotate}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Edit: Following the advice of @David Carlisle, I have changed the default definition of `annotate` by removing spaces and moving registry definitions outside of the environment like this:

```
\newdimen\xtic%
\newdimen\ytic%

\renewenvironment{annotate}[2]%
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#2]%
    \node (pic) at (0,0) {#1};%
    \pgfextractx\xtic{\pgfpointanchor{pic}{east}}%
    \pgfmathparse{int(\xtic/1cm)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xtic{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfextracty\ytic{\pgfpointanchor{pic}{north}}%
    \pgfmathparse{int(\ytic/1cm)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ytic{\pgfmathresult}%
}%
{\end{tikzpicture}}
```

It is still causing spaces however (top is within `annotate` environment). What else could be causing the space?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `\newenvironment{annotate}[2]%[num]%
{ \begin` is inserting a space at the start `{ \end{tikzpicture} }` is inserting two spaces at the end

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you, I didn't even notice that for some reason. That removed some of the space but there is still remaining horizontal and vertical space, I am changing that environment now it is proven to be causing it

Comment: also move `\newdimen\xtic\newdimen\ytic` out of the definiton, you are allocating two registers each time. They are a finite resource, just allocate them once and use each time

Comment: I will email the author afterwards to ask if it can be changed, I am going to copy the virgin `callouts.sty` and modify it in my local dir. I am not sure if I can copy and paste the source into this question though, it is quite a brief file so could make troubleshooting easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As complement to @JamesT answer with mall variation of `annotate` environment redefinition. It may be interesting ...

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{callouts}

\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom,
              font=small, labelfont=bf, labelsep=period, 
              aboveskip=6pt, belowskip=-6pt, 
              singlelinecheck=off, justification=justified}

\newdimen\xtic
\newdimen\ytic

\renewenvironment{annotate}[3][inner sep=0pt]%  <---
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#3]
% Annotate
    \node[#1] (pic) at (0,0) {#2};
    \pgfextractx\xtic{\pgfpointanchor{pic}{east}}
    \pgfmathparse{int(\xtic/1cm)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xtic{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfextracty\ytic{\pgfpointanchor{pic}{north}}
    \pgfmathparse{int(\ytic/1cm)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ytic{\pgfmathresult}
}%
{\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
\begin{annotate}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}} % <---
                {1}
\node[draw] at (-3.55, 2.95) {\textbf{(a)}};
\end{annotate}
\caption{With default annotate annotation settings}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[b]
\begin{annotate}[draw=cyan, line width=2mm, 
                 text width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2mm, 
                 inner sep=0pt]                                         % <---
                {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}   % <---
                {1}
\node[draw] at (-3.55, 2.95) {\textbf{(a)}};
\end{annotate}
\caption{With optional settings of the annotate}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)

Answer (score 0):

Applying the comments by @David Carlisle and editing the `\renewenvironment{annotate}` to include another argument containing options passed to the `\node` contained within the definition gives this:

[image]

The important option is `inner sep=0pt`, for whatever reason this was causing the spaces around the figure when using a `\textwidth` figure.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{callouts}

\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom,labelfont={bf, small}, labelsep=period, textfont={small}, aboveskip=6pt, belowskip=-6pt, singlelinecheck=off, justification=justified}

\newdimen\xtic
\newdimen\ytic

\renewenvironment{annotate}[3]%[num]%
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#2]% }%
% Annotate
    \node[#3] (pic) at (0,0) {#1};%
    \pgfextractx\xtic{\pgfpointanchor{pic}{east}}
    \pgfmathparse{int(\xtic/1cm)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xtic{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfextracty\ytic{\pgfpointanchor{pic}{north}}
    \pgfmathparse{int(\ytic/1cm)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ytic{\pgfmathresult}
}%
{\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{annotate}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}{1}{inner sep=0pt,draw=none,fill=white}
\node[draw] at (-3.55, 2.95) {\textbf{(a)}};
\end{annotate}
\caption{With annotate}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[b]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Without annotate}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I will email the author to ask if the changes by @David Carlisle (removing extra spaces around the `{tikzpicture}` and moving `xtic`/`ytic` out of the definition) and adding a (maybe optional) argument for `\node (pic)` options is possible.